# How to override CSS of a plugin in wordpress from styles.css

Tags: css, wordpress, overriding

I am using the plugin: "Wordpress Contact Form 7".

I want to override the CSS that the plugin uses with my own CSS.
I want to do this in such a way that even if I update this plugin, or change my theme, my changes will still remain.

What is the best way to do this?
So far I have been trying to edit style.css of my theme. But this has produced inadequate results. Since style.css may be loaded before the css of the plugin, the css may be overridden by the plugin. It works only if I specify properties for things that have not been defined in the plugin css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a few modifications to apply, by far the simplest way to override a plugin's stylesheet is to add `body` in front of the element you are targeting within your `style.css` file. Adding `body` adds CSS specificity to the selector, allowing it to override the original styling. Like Reyzis say.

```
body .plugin-class {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: You may have to use `!important` as well.

Comment: I suggest only using `!important` sparsely.
The more exact / specific the CSS locator is, the more important it is.
`body .parent .parent .plugin-class`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this for example?

```css
body {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

edit: sorry - fixed

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.